# Can Nunit able to test Stylecop custom rules?

Tags: c#, nunit, stylecop

Can Nunit V2.6 able to test Stylecop custom rules ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about rules that you create yourself, I would say you can't because custom StyleCop rules rely on external resources: XML configuration file. And [if a test relies on the file system, then it's not a unit test](http://artofunittesting.com/definition-of-a-unit-test/) anymore. However, using [this link](http://blog.drorhelper.com/2010/07/unit-testing-custom-stylecop-rules.html), you should be able to come close to what a unit test can be, using MS test, not NUnit. But I would rather recommend integration testing for such development.

Answer (score 0):

*My answer relies on MS Testing rather than NUnit. If you have TFS it is so simple to change over, otherwise Guillaume's answer seems reasonable.*

**A friend of mine (a ASP.Net MVP) did some amazing work around this (I will summarise the code for interweb history but must attribute the kudos to Tatham Oddie):
[Custom Code Analysis Rules in VS2010 (and how to make them run in FxCop and VS2008 too)](http://blog.tatham.oddie.com.au/2010/01/06/custom-code-analysis-rules-in-vs2010-and-how-to-make-them-run-in-fxcop-and-vs2008-too/)**

**Best to read the article, is has lots of pretty pictures to help follow along.** If the article isn't available and no longer in interwebs cache, here is the method:

1. Start with a new class library project. Make sure you choose to target “.NET Framework 4”
2. Add references to FxCopSdk.dll, Microsoft.Cci.dll and Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.dll. You’ll usually find these in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Team Tools\Static Analysis Tools\FxCop
3. Add a new XML file to your project called Rules.xml. This will be a manifest file that describes each of our individual rules. To get us started, paste in the following content:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Rules FriendlyName="My Custom Rules">
  <Rule TypeName="AllTypeNamesShouldEndInFoo" Category="CustomRules.Naming" CheckId="CR1000">
    <Name>All type names should end in 'Foo'</Name>
    <Description>I like all of my types to end in 'Foo' so that I know they're a type.</Description>
    <Url>http://foobar.com</Url>
    <Resolution>The name of type {0} does not end with the suffix 'Foo'. Add the suffix to the type name.</Resolution>
    <MessageLevel Certainty="95">Warning</MessageLevel>
    <FixCategories>Breaking</FixCategories>
    <Email />
    <Owner />
  </Rule>
</Rules>
```

---

1. Go to the properties for the XML file and change the Build Action to EmbeddedResource so that it gets compiled into our DLL.
2. Create a class called BaseRule and paste in the following code:

---

```
using Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk;

public abstract class BaseRule : BaseIntrospectionRule
{
    protected BaseRule(string name)
        : base(

            // The name of the rule (must match exactly to an entry
            // in the manifest XML)
            name,

            // The name of the manifest XML file, qualified with the
            // namespace and missing the extension
            typeof(BaseRule).Assembly.GetName().Name + ".Rules",

            // The assembly to find the manifest XML in
            typeof(BaseRule).Assembly)
    {
    }
}
```

---

1. Create a class called AllTypeNamesShouldEndInFoo and paste in the following stub code:

---

```
public override ProblemCollection Check(TypeNode type)
{
    if (!type.Name.Name.EndsWith("Foo", StringComparison.Ordinal))
    {
        var resolution = GetResolution(type.Name.Name);
        var problem = new Problem(resolution, type)
                          {
                              Certainty = 100,
                              FixCategory = FixCategories.Breaking,
                              MessageLevel = MessageLevel.Warning
                          };
        Problems.Add(problem);
    }

    return Problems;
}
```

1. Create another class library in your solution called TestLibrary. We won’t put any real code in here – we’re just going to use it as the library to execute our rules against.
2. Add a new Code Analysis Rule Set file to the project
3. When the file opens in the designer you’ll see a list of all the built-in rules. Because custom rules aren’t really supported yet, there’s no nice way of adding our own rules into this list.
4. In Solution Explorer, right click on the .ruleset file, choose Open With and select XML Editor from the options. This will show you the raw contents of the file, which is currently pretty boring. To point Visual Studio in the direction of your custom rules, you then add a series of hint paths.

This is what the rule set XML looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="New Rule Set" Description="" ToolsVersion="10.0">
  <RuleHintPaths>
    <Path>C:\Temp\CARules\BlogDemo\BlogDemo.CodeAnalysisRules\bin\Debug</Path>
  </RuleHintPaths>
</RuleSet>
```

1. Make sure you have compiled your rules project, then go back to Solution Explorer, right click on the .ruleset file, choose Open With and select Code Analysis Rule Set Editor.
2. Now, you should see your custom rule loaded into the list.

Comment: hmmm, my point numbering resets after inserting code blocks, anyone know the fix?